# Automatic conversion of wrapper in C#

Tags: c#, wrapper, non-nullable, preconditions

I've build wrapper-class intended to prevent reference types of being null, as a pre-condition code contract.

```
public sealed class NotNullable<T> 
    where T : class
{
    private T t;

    public static implicit operator NotNullable<T>(T otherT)
    {
        otherT.CheckNull("Non-Nullable type");
        return new NotNullable<T> {t = otherT};
    }

    public static implicit operator T(NotNullable<T> other)
    {
        return other.t;
    }

}
```

This works finely, but a cast is always needed like when dealing with Nullable:

```
public void Foo(NonNullable<Bar> bar)
{
    Console.WriteLine((Bar)bar);
}
```

Would it be possible to have the parameter of type NonNullable behave as if it were of type T, without having to cast it?
Like in Spec#:

```
public string Foo(Bar! bar)
```

Comment: yes and no, yes - if you write your own compiler/pre-processor... no if you just use C# as is AFAIK...

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the casting by making the object itself accessible via a `Value` property, but it's debatable whether that's any better than casting it:

```
Console.WriteLine(bar.Value);
```

There are even tricks you can use to tell tools like ReSharper that this value is not null, either via XML or in-code annotations:

```
[NotNull]
public T Value { get { return t; } }
```